# Gamma function and Time scale calculus

Tags: analysis, factorial, gamma-function

The conclusion of the following link

[Does Gamma function a solution for known Ordinary differential equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3304165/)

is

> "$\Gamma(x)$ function is impossible to characterize by algebraic
> differential equation"

So 'Differential equation' is ***not good weapon*** for characterizing gamma.

But I found some articles in stackexchange math, asserting that "**time scale calculus** is a part of mathematics which unifies recurrence relation and differential equation".

But I know nothing of time scale calculus.
Can I hope "time scale calculus" is a good weapon for characterizing Gamma from the factorial recurrence relation $x_n = n x_{n-1}$ ?

Bohr–Mollerup theorem is about extending factorial recurrence relation to Gamma function.
But one can hope similar logic for other similar  recurrence relation to some function. Does time scale calculus deal with such problems ?

Comment: I doubt that the time scale calculus will be very useful, but generalizations of Bohr–Mollerup to similar recurrences are studied, see e.g. [A Generalization of Bohr-Mollerup's Theorem for Higher Order Convex Functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.14742) and [Multiple Gamma Function, Its $q$ and Elliptic Analogue](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44238658) for typical methods. You may also want to look into [summability calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3220941/152568).

Comment: Thank you! The paper in the first link is very recent!